# Configure mail account in Outlook in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, email, microsoft-outlook, gmail

I am running Mac OS X and I have setup Windows XP in my virtualbox.
I want to configure a Gmail account in outlook 2003. (don't ask me why)

The connection of Windows XPp in virtualbox is set to "nas".

In Outlook, the incoming email server (pop3) is set to: imap.gmail.com
But the program can't make a connection to this server. In the program mail in Mac OS X,
this works. So I assume I have to set something up in virtualbox.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that imap.gmail.com is stands for [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP), but from your comment it appears that you trying to configure [POP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop3) mail. I think [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OI5U0IfBZg) should help you.